# ListPlot data-point discretization causes jitter in animation

Tags: plotting

I'm doing some animations and notice that ListPlot seems to discretize positions of points at some point ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-jumpy-listplot.nb)). This causes undesirable jumpiness in the plot

Any suggestions where this discretization happens/how to fix it?
[image]

Crop from full animation [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eocye9w3ec7kiwn/gradientScales1.gif?dl=0)